# QTableWidget use the parent available size

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtablewidget

I qt I added a QTableWidget. I tried different ways to add this to a layout but the QTableWidget has always its default size.
Sure I can set the "Minimumwidth" but tI expected that the QTableWidget will use the whole available space, same like every other widget too.

```
this->horizontalHeader()->hide();
    this->verticalHeader()->hide();
    this->setRowCount(m_numRows);
    this->setColumnCount(m_numCols);
    this->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    this->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(12);
    this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

I also tried

```
 this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);
```

What is the secret to use the whole available space with QTableWidget?

Comment: but what is the layoutstrech ???

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you will add a widget to a `QLayout` instance as an intermediary between a widget and its parent widget, to automatically handle the positioning and sizing of the widget relative to its parent widget. For example, the following shows how to achieve this for a `QTableWidget`.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QTableWidget>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QMainWindow mainWindow;
  mainWindow.setCentralWidget(new QWidget);

  QHBoxLayout layout;
  layout.addWidget(new QTableWidget(mainWindow.centralWidget()));

  mainWindow.centralWidget()->setLayout(&layout);
  mainWindow.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

This example is a bit contrived. A main window is special in the sense that you could have set the `QTableWidget` instance as the central widget, and it would have been laid out nicely by `QMainWindow` automatically.

To demonstrate the functionality of `QLayout`, a separate central widget is created, and the table widget is added to the layout set on the central widget. In case you would not set the layout on the central widget (comment out the `setLayout(...)` call), you will probably get behavior similar to what you already have.

Finally, `QHBoxLayout` can be replaced by `QVBoxLayout` to achieve the same result of course. Only when you add multiple widgets to the same layout, it starts to matter which implementation of a `QLayout` you choose.